Windows Server 2012 R2 not listening for RDP connections
My last domain joined Windows Server 2012 R2 server has stopped responding to RDP connections.  If any Remote Desktop client tries to connect it just sits at Initiating remote connection until it times out.  I can connect to the server using our VNC software and I confirmed that:

Remote desktop is enabled (by GPO for all servers)
The firewall is not blocking RDP connections (fails whether the firewall is on or off)
IP/DNS, etc. is correct (all other connections like web, vnc, etc. work fine)
There are no error/warning event log entries in any of the Applications and Service Logs/Microsoft/Windows/RemoteDesktopServices* or TerminalServices*.
There are no recent Windows patches (the last one was from July and we were connecting fine up until a week ago).

I installed Wireshark on the machine and I can see the connection attempts but no responses.  Use Netstat -oan I can see that nothing is listening on port 3389 so I checked the Terminal Services registry key and that is the port RDP is set to use.
Any suggestions as to what else I could look for would be most helpful.

Windows 2012R2 is end of life. Upgrade to a supported release.

I would love to but the application running on it doesn't support newer OS versions.  We're working on getting the application updated but its taking a while and this not working doesn't help that process.

You need to check the registry valueS that enables and  disables RDP. HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services!fDenyTSConnections and HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server!fDenyTSConnections.

Use Netstat -oan I can see that nothing is listening on port 3389 - Did you check that the RDS service is actually running?

@GregAskew-fDenyTSConnections is 0 in both locations.

@joeqwerty-Yes, the RDS service is running.  In fact I tried restarting it but that didn't help.
